# How to normalize values but keep them all positive

Tags: normalization, z-score

I have an array of speed values that I would like to normalize. However, I need no value to be negative as I am doing a transformation of this data later on using division with revolutions per minute. Previously I was using a z-score however this will return negative values. If I simply square the negative values this will give the indication that the new value is larger than the mean so that is also out of the question.

Comment: Min-max normalization.

Comment: I think that the answer to your question depends on what you mean with "normalize". It is not a fixed definition. Could you clarify that?

Comment: What is the purpose of the normalization? What problem are you trying to solve? For example, you could use $\tanh(x)+1$ as a normalization, and it will always be positive, but it might not satisfy some requirement you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple normalization methods are available based on use-case.

[Min-Max Scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler) could be used to normalize in range [0, 1]. Can be tweaked for the desired range. It also preserves shape of distribution.

You can additionally use any fixed range function like **sigmoid, tanh** (tanh + 1) for normalizing based on requirements.

[towardsdatascience article on scalers](https://towardsdatascience.com/scale-standardize-or-normalize-with-scikit-learn-6ccc7d176a02)